# Plunker account without linking to Github: possible?

Tags: authentication, github, account, plunker

As much as possible, I avoid using cross-login (eg: using Facebook credentials to log into a non-Facebook site) to mitigate privacy and security breach exposures.

I'd like to start saving the work I do in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/), so I need an account. However, the only option I see is to use [Github](https://github.com/) to login.

Is there a way to get a Plunker account without providing Github credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no mechanism to create an account on Plunker without using Github. Please be conscious that the scopes required by Plunker are only for identification purposes.

I plan to open Plunker to aditional identity providers in the future but have no plans to allow username and password logins.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of your answer since anyone on Stack with no link to Plunker could post an identical message (any ref to a Plunker page with the info would help) but I thank you for taking the time to share the information. +1

Comment: Hello @BeetleJuice, perhaps you would find this sufficient proof: https://github.com/filearts/plunker_www/issues/94

Comment: Thank you for the link, and for the answer. Hope I didn't offend.

Comment: If you feel up to it (I understand it's beyond the original question's scope), please leave a line about why you chose to outsource user authentication. Does it not worry you that you rely on a 3rd party to let you know who your users are? What happens to you if Github goes away or disables that service?

Comment: @BeetleJuice the reason auth is outsourced is that building such a service in a secure and reliable way is _hard_. I know this first-hand as an employee of Auth0. However, at the time Plunker was created, I was not working anywhere near the IT industry, did not have my current knowledge and skills, and Github OAuth was a relevant (to my userbase) and easy solution.